# How can I merge a specific file from one branch into another branch in Git

Tags: git

I have 2 branches in a git repo, lets call them, dev and test.  I have changes in a single file, somecode.js.  Both branches have changes to somecode.js.  The 2 branches have diverged significantly (but manageably) so a straight "merge" is insufficient.

I have tried http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/ but it doesn't merge the contents of both files.  You basically just write over the file instead of actually merging the contents of the file.

I have also tried:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
git checkout test somecode.js
git commit -m "somecode changes from newbranch"
git checkout dev
git merge newbranch
```

And

```
git checkout -m test somecode.js
```

(I was really hopeful with the -m for merge, but it didn't appear to work for me...)

I thought I was close to what I needed, but then I realized that it just fast-forwarded the commit meaning it didn't merge, it wrote over the original file in test.

So, to reiterate, how can I merge a specific file from one branch into another branch without just writing over the file in the branch I am merging into using git.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449541/how-do-you-merge-selective-files-with-git-merge

Comment: Cherry-pick doesn't solve the problem because that incorporates complete commits.  So it will bring over multiple files and I'll have to look through all the commits to see which are relevant

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I merge changes to a single file, rather than merging commits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784523/how-do-i-merge-changes-to-a-single-file-rather-than-merging-commits)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think you like to use

```
git checkout -p
```

In your case

```
git checkout dev
git checkout -p test somecode.js
```

And you can interactively apply the diffs.

Comment: But you don't allow git to do any merge.. you manually do all the work.

Comment: @the.malkolm At the first question you reply with `a` and that's it. (a - apply this hunk and all later hunks in the file)

Comment: It just means you apply 'theirs' strategy.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't seem to work for me.  The message after ``git checkout -p [other_branch] [path_to_file][filename]`` was simply "No changes," which summed up the result perfectly.  Perhaps I'm trying to drag in a directory/file that doesn't exist in my current branch???

Comment: @ScottBiggs - this is probably because `other_branch` was already merged into your current branch. I'm not sure how to work around that yet.

Comment: git merge -p does not appear to be a valid git option anymore! can anyone confirm? I am on git version 2.7.4

Answer (score 5):

```
git checkout dev
git show test:somecode.js > somecode.js.theirs
git show $(git merge-base dev test):somecode.js > somecode.js.base
git merge-file somecode.js somecode.js.base somecode.js.theirs
```

This way you'll manually make a three-way merge from somecode.js on test branch into somecode.js on dev branch.

Or.. You can create a temporary branch with the changes you want and make a squash merge from it. Is it 'git way' enough? :)

```
git checkout -b test/filtered $(git merge-base dev test)
git diff ..test -- somecode.js | git apply
git add -- somecode.js
git commit -m "Updated somecode.js"
git checkout dev
git merge --squash test/filtered
git branch -D test/filtered
```

Comment: I suppose that works, but I'm hoping for a "git-way" to do it.  I'll wait for a few more answers and approve this if I can't figure out a git-way.

Comment: Is this one 'git way' enough? :)

Comment: I was hoping for something like "git checkout -m test somecode.js"

Answer (score 1):

I think git merge-file is what you're looking for. From the man page:

```
git merge-file incorporates all changes that lead from the <base-file> to
<other-file> into <current-file>. The result ordinarily goes into <current-file>.
git merge-file is useful for combining separate changes to an original. Suppose
<base-file> is the original, and both <current-file> and <other-file> are
modifications of <base-file>, then git merge-file combines both changes.
```

Comment: I don't see a way to specify the file from the other branch.  This looks like it is for internal use perhaps?  Can you show usage?

Comment: `git merge-file` is just the 3-way merge driver for files. That description is a bit misleading; it doesn't look at all the commits in between, it just does a classic 3-way merge.