# How to merge first branch from the other remote branch?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a branch called B1. I want to merge some files from the B2 branch and I want to commit them. How can I merge with other branch details?

Comment: Did you try `git merge B2`? Did you have any problems? It's kind of a very basic operation that shouldn't have given you any problems. If you did have problems, could you explain what they were? Did you want to selectively merge only ***some*** of the commits from the `B2` branch into `B1`, instead of all of them?

Comment: Did you only want to merge individual files, instead of entire commits? If so, then [How to merge specific files from Git branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115411/how-to-merge-specific-files-from-git-branches) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge a branch in Git, do the following:

```
git checkout B1
git merge B2
```

To learn more about branching in Git, see [Git Branching](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching). To learn more about Git basics, I highly recommend the [***FREE*** online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book), in particular chapters 1-3, 6-6.5.

If you only wanted to merge ***some*** of the commits from the `B2` branch, you have the option of using `git cherry-pick <sha-of-commit>`.  If instead you want to take only the changes to a particular file `X` in `B2`, then you could use `checkout`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115411/how-to-merge-specific-files-from-git-branches/18115667#18115667) to [How to merge specific files from Git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115411/how-to-merge-specific-files-from-git-branches):

```
git checkout B1
git checkout B2 X
```