# How to ignore specific files during merging of branches in Git?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-merge, git-branch

I have some environment specific files in a Git repo.

When I merge my dev branch to master, I don't want to overwrite those files in master with the ones from dev.

How can I set those files to be ignored when merging the branches?

Comment: Don't commit config files.

Comment: It needs to be committed because Jenkins needs it. Not config actually, more like specifications.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge specific files from Git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115411/how-to-merge-specific-files-from-git-branches)

Comment: Not really. It's kind of the opposite of what I want.

Comment: The thinking is still the same, however. You first merge (without committing) and throw away only the file changes you don't want.

Comment: I tried some of the stuff from the answers like gitattributes and it didn't seem to work for my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge and then just check them out:

```
git merge some_branch --no-commit -m "some merge"
git checkout HEAD -- file1 file2 file3
git merge --continue
```

You might set GIT_EDITOR to /bin/true if the process is going on in a script:

```
GIT_EDITOR=/bin/true git merge --continue
```

Comment: This workaorund seems to be working. Would have liked to have something like .gitignore for merging but this would work for now. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

If you push any file to `.git` and merge the branch to `master` , it will definitely override the master branch files. No. way to prevent this.

Instead of this, create different `config` files for different environments and configure `Jenkins` to use those files.

Comment: I wish it was that simple for the files to be configured for Jenkins because different repos are running with different configurations. But thanks for suggestion.