# How can I update a git branch from another branch when there are files that do not share?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have two branches `master` and `docs`. The second one has files that I never want in the  `master` branch, however when I perform an update in `master` I would like to update the `docs` branch without altering its extra files.

I tried to use `merge`, however, it fails due to the extra files in the `docs` branch.

Can you help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: It's most likely possible using some combination of flags on some git command, but I'd say – it's a sign you're not using git "right" (not to your advantage). It sounds like `docs` should be a folder, not a branch.

Comment: What do you mean by the merge "fails"? Unless there is something you have not included in your questions it should be possible to merge `master` into `docs` despite `docs` having files that `master` does not.

Comment: The error when I try to merge is: 

`Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files. hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'`

and only when I delete the extra files (or add them in `master`), it works.

Comment: That particular error message (`you have unmerged files`) implies that you already started a merge earlier, and have not yet finished it. You cannot start a *new* merge until you finish, or terminate, the earlier one.

Comment: did you try to rebase docs?

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting specific files or directories from the `master` branch in the `docs` branch works for me. For example, assuming that `directory_to_update` is older in the `docs` branch, I did the following to update (overwrite) it with respect to `master`:

```
$ git checkout docs
$ git checkout master directory_to_update
```

Then the following message appears: `Updated N paths from ...`, and the files have been "updated".

Similar to the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18115667/7749658