# Pulling Just One Folder from One Branch to A Different Branch Git

Tags: git, github

I have two branches A and B,
B was branched off from A

there were different changes made on both A and B since then

I would like to know the git commands to move just one folder from A to B without pulling any other changes

Answer (score 1):

[How do I merge changes to a single file, rather than merging commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784523/how-do-i-merge-changes-to-a-single-file-rather-than-merging-commits) is basically the same question, but many of the answers are wrong.

I fixed/improved some of the better solutions.

- To merge the changes and get the commits too (this will cause duplicate commits if you later merge A and B, could be avoided with rebase):

  ```
  git checkout B
  git format-patch --stdout ..A -- <path> | git am -3
  ```
- To merge the changes without the commits, use [this answer (be aware A and B is swapped)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12717678/6597851)  or this simpler solution:

  ```
  git checkout B
  git diff ...A -- <path> | git apply
  # stage changes and commit
  ```
- To overwrite B with the version of the files in A:

  ```
  git checkout B
  git checkout A -- <path>
  # commit
  ```